# Application lagging after a limit of widgets

Tags: go, user-interface, lag, fyne

I have a few widgets on my main view, but when I add a new one, it exceeds the "limit" of widgets until it starts lagging. I've tried using different goroutines but I think that in a gui application that's not the case.
Here is a screenshot of **before it lags**:

[image: Before]

and **after**:

[image: After]

I'm not an expert in this type of problems regarding performance but I don't know why this happens, **it seems like there is a sort of limit of widgets before it starts lagging**.
I tried even removing the functions from the buttons leaving them with no use, but the program still lags.
If I hide those three buttons though, it doesn't lag anymore.
Anyone is aware of the problem?

Comment: Fyne apps can have hundreds or thousands of widgets and do not lag.
I think your question may need to provide some code or more specific details of what sort of lag you are experiencing.

Comment: @andy.xyz I just add those three buttons with a new container and add the container to the main window of course, and the application starts lagging, by lagging I mean that it starts going slow (5 fps)

Comment: What aspects are moving at 5fps? It’s not clear from your image that there are any animations. If you can display more specifically what you see it may help to understand.

Comment: The whole application framelags, especially the split container when trying to resize it and I don't understand why. I should probably try to recreate a new project and see.

Comment: Please do, this is a most strange problem that has not been reported before

Comment: ok, thanks anyway for the response @andy.xyz